# bundler version issue in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I am getting this bundler error how do i resolve it.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.11.3) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.3.12)

Your bundle requires a different version of Bundler than the one you're running.
Install the necessary version with `gem install bundler:2.0.0.pre.3` and rerun bundler using `bundle _2.0.0.pre.3_`
```

What do `gem install bundler:2.0.0.pre.3` and `bundle _2.0.0.pre.3_` command gonna do. Are they gonna replace my `2.3.12` and install `2.0.0`

Comment: I think it will add another version of bundler into your Gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be multiple versions of the same gem installed in your gemset. Run this:

```
gem install bundler:2.0.0.pre.3
```

and then run this:

```
gem info bundler
```

you will find two versions of the gem installed. By default, it will run `bundle` with the latest version but as your gems are not compatible with it you can run `bundle` with a different version of the gem. To do that you need to run:

```
bundle _version_
```

in your case it will be:

```
bundle _2.0.0.pre.3_
```

You can also remove the other versions of the `bundler` gem and just keep the one that is compatible. To remove a specific version you could do:

```
gem uninstall bundler:2.3.12
```